# Disable autobrightness on PC

Tags: windows-10, brightness, nvidia-settings

My screen's brightness auto change sometimes when I watch a movie or play games. Especially when I toggle Tab menu on/off in league of legends, my screen start diming/lighting, also when I toggle the samsung monitor menu.

I have tried: power plan, monitor services, driver update, dynamic contrast, full range color and many solutions with google.

My PC's spec: i3 6100, gtx1050ti, win 10 pro, samsung ls24f350 monitor. Please help me!

Answer (score 1):

In Windows 10 build 15063 (1703), you should be able to control it at:
Settings > System > Display > Change brightness automatically when lighting changes.  (I think it's same with older Windows 10 builds, but I cannot verity that right now.)

[image: Screen shot]